# CSS '+' selector not working

Tags: css

I am trying to create some margin between 2 divs when the both of them have a common parent, so the code as it follows:

```
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">hello</div>
      <div class="child">hello</div>
   </div>
```

and css

```
 .child{background:#ccc; padding:20px}
 .parent .child + .parent .child{ margin-top:520px; }
```

you can see in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/hjcY7/

And also in the link there is another example that it works but when the div dont have a parent.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the rule this way:

```
.parent .child + .child {
   margin-top: 520px;
}
```

You can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/hjcY7/1/.

Take a look at the [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) on W3.